# Tracking embed Facebook video on GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am trying to track embedded Facebook video in my website using Google Tag Manager. How do I proceed to track it? Not able to find any solution from the website.

Thank You.

Comment: Anyone has idea?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/api